# I am trying to solve the following first order linear inhomogeneous ODE. $a'_n(t) + 4\pi ^2 n^2 a_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}\left[ t(-1)^n-1\right]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following first order linear inhomogeneous ODE.

$$a'_n(t) + 4\pi ^2 n^2 a_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}\left[ t(-1)^n-1\right]$$

Solving for $y_h$ I get the following,

$$m+4n^2 \pi ^2 = 0 $$
$$m = -4\pi ^2 n^2 $$
$$y_h = ce^{-4n^2 \pi ^2 t }$$

Its solving for $y_p $ where I am having trouble, I am trying to solve it through method of undetermined coefficients.

I tried with the form $y = At+b$

So,

$$A + 4\pi ^2 n^2(At+b) = \frac{2}{n\pi}\left[ t(-1)^n-1\right]$$

$$A + 4\pi ^2 n^2At + 4\pi ^2 n^2B = \frac{2t(-1)^n}{n\pi} - \frac{2}{n \pi}$$

So then $A = \frac{(-1)^nt}{2(n\pi)^3}, B = \frac{-1}{2(n\pi )^3}$

However the answer is the following and I am not sure where I am going wrong,

$$a_n(t) =  ce^{-4n^2 \pi ^2 t } +\frac{(-1)^nt}{2(n\pi)^3} - \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{8(n\pi )^5} + \frac{1}{2(n\pi )^3} \right)\left( 1-e^{-4(n\pi)^2t}\right)$$

Comment: what denotes $$\alpha_n(t)$$?

Comment: this was just part of a PDE problem that I am having trouble with solving this first order system

Comment: was my trial form of $at+b $ correct to use or should I use another?

Comment: i got this here $$\alpha_n(t)=c_1 e^{-4 \pi ^2 n^2 t}+\frac{4 \pi ^2 n^2 \left((-1)^n
   t-1\right)+(-1)^{n+1}}{8 \pi ^5 n^5}$$

Comment: what trial form did you use? and what about the $1-e^{-4(n\pi )^2 t}$ part? I may have copied the answer down wrong in my notes I am using

Comment: this is the solution of your equation

Comment: okay thanks, its a little different than the answer I thought I was supposed to be getting

Comment: you can use the solution and check if the equation is fulfilled

Comment: okay thanks for your time

Comment: To find the particular use the integrating factor method 
$$a_{n}^{p}(t)=\frac{2}{n\pi}e^{-4\pi^{2}n^{2}t}\int^{t}{e^{4\pi^{2}n^{2}s}(s(-1)^n-1)}ds$$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html

Comment: could you show how this is evaluated? thanks for that tip btw

Comment: @user123, yes, to get  'a' particular solution you can use the trial form $y_p(t)=at+b$.

Comment: @Wang so why am I not getting the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trial form is correct. By differentiation we have
$$
A + 4\pi ^2 n^2At + 4\pi ^2 n^2B =\color{red}{4\pi^2n^2A}t+\color{blue}{A+ 4\pi ^2 n^2B}= \color{red}{\frac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi}}t \color{blue}{- \frac{2}{n \pi}}
$$
Then, by identification we get
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
4\pi^2n^2A=\frac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi}\\
A+ 4\pi ^2 n^2B=- \frac{2}{n \pi}  \end{array}\right. \Rightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A=\frac{(-1)^n}{2(\pi n)^3}\\
B=-\frac{1}{2(\pi n)^3}-\frac{(-1)^n}{8(\pi n)^5}.  \end{array}\right.$$
Hence, $$y_p(t)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2(\pi n)^3}t-\frac{1}{2(\pi n)^3}-\frac{(-1)^n}{8(\pi n)^5}.$$
This is a solution of the inhomogeneous equation, and the mentioned solution, in the question, is an other one. Note that the difference between these 2 particular solutions has the form of $y_h$.

Comment: how did you solve for A and B?

Comment: @user123: clarified in the answer.

Comment: @Weng thanks for your help, it was really helpful! The solution for $A$ should be $\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi ^3 n^3}$, actually I'm not sure if it is or not but that makes sense with the calculation of B?

Comment: @user123: rectified; thanks.